# How to set the height of a PDF header?

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, cfdocument

Does anyone know how I can set the height of a header in a pdf generated by `<cfdocumentitem format="pdf:...`?

I am using `<cfdocumentitem type="header">`

So have something like

```
<cfdocument format="pdf" marginbottom="0" margintop="4" marginleft="0" marginright="0" pagetype="a4" unit="cm" fontembed="no">
<cfdocumentitem type="header">
  This is my header.. I want to reduce the height but can't work out how.
<cfdocumentitem>
</cfdocument>
```

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Jason

Comment: Have you tried adding CSS to it?

Comment: What would I be adding the CSS to?  I did try putting a div wrapper around the header content and applying CDs to that but only impacted the div.. Not the header container. What selector would I apply CSS to to manipulate the document header?  Thanks Mark

Comment: Jason, you would have to experiment. Probably height, font-size, line-height etc.

Comment: Thanks Mark, my question was more around what element I would apply the styles to as opposed to what styles I would use. The header is cf tag, not an html element and it doesn't have a css attribute that styles can be passed into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the margin settings in the **cfdocument** tag to control how much space is reserved for headers or footers.

So in your case, change the margintop value from 4 to a lower value.

```
<cfdocument format="pdf" marginbottom="0" margintop="4" marginleft="0" marginright="0" pagetype="a4" unit="cm" fontembed="no">
```

To further control the appearance of your header, such as padding, line-height, you would need to add HTML and CSS styles to your header content.

Comment: THanks CFSimplicity.. worked well. Doesn't allow pixel level control, but certainly acheived what I needed to.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use marginTop = "number" in cfdocument.

```
<cfdocument
format = "PDF|FlashPaper"
authPassword = "authentication password"
authUser = "authentication user name"
backgroundVisible = "yes|no"
bookmark = "yes|no"
encryption = "128-bit|40-bit|none"
filename = "filename"
fontEmbed = "yes|no"
localUrl = "yes|no"
marginBottom = "number"
marginLeft = "number"
marginRight = "number"
marginTop = "number"
....
```