# Coldfusion - Dynamic Page Break

Tags: printing, coldfusion

I have a form which has a table which may contain 0 rows or several rows.
The problem is that if there are several rows I want close the table on the first page before the content spills over to the next page. Then create another table for the rest of the rows on the next page along with a nice header and table headings. The hard part is, because characters have different widths and I can't predict what the user will type, it's hard to calculate how many characters can fit on a row and how many rows can fit on a page. Also if the user types something in some of the row data, it wraps to a 2nd row.
The printout looks bad when the row has only a few rows because there is a lot of whitespace on the bottom so I was thinking of adding in blank rows to fill it up. But again, I won't exactly know how many rows I need to fill before it spills onto the next page.
Does anyone have a solution to this?

EDIT:

Sorry about that. To be more clear on what I'm doing, I created a form view using CF and HTML which mimics visually like a paper invoice. Invoice line items can be added in dynamically via AJAX. There's a bunch of info to be filled out on top (Company name, address, etc), then in the middle there's the invoice lines in a table with column headings, then under it there's more info to fill out including signature fields. This format cannot be changed as it is a requirement.

So the form layout is:

Top section (info including customer info and a bunch of other things)

Middle section (table of invoice line items)

Bottom section (a bunch of other info including signature fields)

Visually on the page the above format is maintained and if there's a lot of invoice line items added, the page just scrolls and the bottom section is still at the end.

An unlimited number of invoice lines can be added so if you simply just print the page, the invoice lines will overflow onto the next page and the "bottom info" including signatures will be on whatever page the last page may be, which is undesired.
I need it so that whatever number of lines that can fit on the first page without having the form overflow be displayed on the first page along with the "bottom info" including signature. The extra lines are displayed on the next pages with headings "Continuation Page" along with the table column headings of the invoice lines.

My solution is to create a "print view" which creates the form with entered info and cfloops the invoice lines query but only loop just enough to fill the first page. If the addition of another row makes the form overflow then I would stop the loop, display the rest of the form with the "bottom info" and signatures so it all fits on the first page nicely, then do a page break with the header "Coninuation Page" and display the invoice line table with column headers and the rest of the invoice line items. Of course if the continuation page is going to overflow then I would need to do a page break and repeat the "Continuation Page" process. The tricky part is how to determine how many lines can actually fit on the page because the length of data in each row varies depending on user input. Maybe only one invoice line row filled with tons of data is all that can fit on the first page without having the form overflow. Maybe it's 10 invoice line rows when little data is entered.

My main purpose is to keep the entire form on the first page. If several invoice line items are added which pushes the bottom of the form onto the next page then I want to display only enough invoice line rows to keep the form on the first page and have a Continuation Page for the rest of the invoice lines that didn't fit on subsequent pages.

Note: The print is done via a print link on the form page which pops up the print view  page (without site heading, etc.) in another window. From there they can either print from the browser or click on a print link that does a javascript print. the same "print view" I created to print the invoice nicely is also used for a PDF view created using CFDocument. The number of characters per line is not the same in the generated PDF as the HTML print view so it's even harder to determine how many rows can fit.

Comment: Ask an explicit question and you'll get an explicit answer. Your question is too vague to answer.

Comment: Are you generating mark-up? A PDF? How is this stuff being printed? Via CFPRINT? Via a web browser? WHat are you actually asking here? Put yourself in our shoes - who don't already know what you're talking about - and reword the question so someone who has only what you say in the question to go on will be able to answer it.

Comment: Recommending reading this: http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2013/09/short-self-contained-correct-compilable.html. And then the link Adam Tuttle includes in a comment of same: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: I wonder if this a CSS for print media question

Comment: @JamesMohler: quite possibly. Very hard to tell though, innit?

Comment: Added more information to the question. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Look up CSS for @media print and then look up the capabilities of your target browsers. Getting a web page to print properly is a battle. For this reason some people prefer PDFs. Of course PDF has its own problems. You may want to check out: http://davidwalsh.name/css-page-breaks

Comment: Got the page break and @media print working. The issue I'm having is trying to determine how many lines I can fit on the first page without having the bottom of the form spill out onto the next page. Because the content in each line varies based on user input, it's a challenge. If they put a lot of content then maybe only 1 fat line can fit on the first page. If they type only a word, maybe 10 lines can fit. I'm trying to keep the main structure of the form (top section, invoice line section, bottom section) on the first page. Invoice lines that don't fit are displayed the following pages

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then a PDF generated with CFDocument would seem to be the optimal solution.  Using the cfdocumentitem tag you can specify headers and footers, which insure that the content you want appears on the first page.  The cfdocument.currentpagenumber variable can be used to insure that it only appears on page one, and that the header on pages 2+ display the "Continuation Page" text that you desire.  There is also a way to get the PDF to auto-print using a DDX file, though that is subject to security limitations.

You mention using CFDocument to create a separate print view, but I didn't see an explanation as to why an HTML version was required as well.  I apologize if I missed it.

From personal experience with a similar project last year I would tend to recommend against using CSS for this and instead just require a PDF reader.  It's possible that someone with more skill than I could make it work easily, but it was nothing but a headache for us and we could never get it to work quite right.

Comment: Currently I am using CFDocument to generate my PDFs. How it's currently done is I have the cfdocumentitem header with my title then I include a form view which contains the form content. Then at the end I have the cfdocumentitem footer with the page number. The problem is in the form view the number of line items are variable. Sometimes it can be only 1 line, sometimes it's 100 lines. I want to be able to put just enough lines so that the rest of the form won't get pushed onto the next page and only the overflow of line items go on the continuation page.

Comment: The problem with your solution is that if I add the form content in the cfdocumentitem header and footer, it just shrinks the text to make it fit in the header at the top and footer at the bottom while whatever I display in the middle will be displayed normal size. I need it to display in normal size for all lines and push only lines that will cause to overflow onto the continuation page. Keep in mind that even if I limit it to 5 lines on the first page, the content of a line can be variable and long in which case maybe only 1 line can fit on the first page without overflowing.

Comment: The CFDocument is only used to create the PDF. It shares the form view with a print view which is in HTML and CF to generate and populate the form. I have a print view because in the normal user view, they can dynamically add invoice lines via ajax and the form will keep growing. The print view currently limits the first page to contain X numbers of line items to prevent the form from overflowing. Then the rest of the lines go on the continuation pages. But again, the issue is even if I limit to X lines, if line 1 has a lot of content,the form may overflow so it won't work all the time.

Comment: Please see this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610026/how-to-set-the-height-of-a-pdf-header .  By defining margins you can leave all the room needed for your header, then let CF take care of page breaking.  The problem we run into is that long lines may be broken half way through.  The only way I know of around that is to measure lines and apply manual page breaks; perhaps with a fixed-width font and character/word counting.  It sounds complicated, but I'm sure a CF function could be whipped up to do it easily enough.

Comment: It sounds like the html version is used for editing only, while we have the leeway to go with cfDocument for the printable version.  Did I understand that correctly?

Comment: The edit version has an html form version which keeps expanding when new line items are added while the cfdocument and print view uses (shares) a "print" html form version which is similar to the edit version except I currently limit the cfloop to display the line items to 5 lines and display the rest on a continuation page. This "print" html version that is used by the cfdocument and print views are what I'm having issues with because even if I limit it to 5 lines on the main page, if users add longer text it can still cause the form to overflow to the next page.

Comment: When the user wants to print the page they must click the print link which pops up a new window containing the "print" html view so it'll display the page properly with limited line items on the main page so it won't overflow and the rest of the lines on the continuation page.